# Is HTML5 localstorage quota shared?

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm planning to use the HTML LocalStorage capability of browsers (FF especially) to store data of our **intranet** application.

I've read about it, how to use, the per domain isolation of data, how the user may increase it's quota, and so on.

But the question is if this quota is shared? Or does each domain has 5Mb to use?

(*) And, if I need to use, say 25Mb, and I ask my clients to increase their browser quota, does that means that all other domains may have this 25MB at disposal?

Or, if another domain uses all of the quota, is there no space left to my app?

**UPDATE:**

There's a (sub)question related to change browser config to allow more space (*). Althrough the below [seems to be a recomendation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#webstorage), does anyone knows if is that implemented on FF?

> > 11.3 Disk space
>
> User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage
>   areas, because hostile authors could otherwise use this feature to
>   exhaust the user's available disk space.
>
> User agents should guard against sites storing data under their
>   origin's other affiliated sites, e.g. storing up to the limit in
>   a1.example.com, a2.example.com, a3.example.com, etc, circumventing the
>   main example.com storage limit.
>
> **User agents may prompt the user when quotas are reached, allowing the
>   user to grant a site more space.** This enables sites to store many
>   user-created documents on the user's computer, for instance.
>
> **User agents should allow users to see how much space each domain is
>   using.**
>
> A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is suggested.
>   Implementation feedback is welcome and will be used to update this
>   suggestion in the future.
>
> For predictability, quotas should be based on the uncompressed size of
>   data stored.

Answer (score 2):

No, the quota is not shared across domains.

The reason for this is as you said - one domain might use up the browser's entire quota, and leave nothing for other sites.

To see how much storage is provided across different browsers, and to test your own, you can visit http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/